# After changing AppPool to .Net 4, any simple aspx page stopped loading

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7.5

I have a web application that I recently upgraded to .Net Framework 4. The application is running on our production server OK. However, I am trying to get it set up on my local Windows 2008R2 dev computer where it was running previously under .Net Framework 2. However whenever I try to load an aspx page, I get a "Value cannot be null" error. An example of the error page with stack trace is listed below;

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the   current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value]
   System.String.IndexOf(String value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 count, StringComparison comparisonType) +400
   System.String.Contains(String value) +25
   MainNet.Global.Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +173
System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +142
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +92
```

Listed below is a simple text aspx page that will create this error;

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>This is a test page</h1>
    <h3>  1 + 2 = <%= (1+2).ToString() %></h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have the ISAPI and CGI Restrictions in IIS set to "Allowed" for ASP.NET v4.0.30319

The directory rights have not changed from when the website ran using APS.NET v2.0.50727

The example code above runs properly under ASP.Net 2

What am i missing here?

Comment: Is the code provided where the error is coming from? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: Added stack trace

Comment: You need to learn to read a stack trace. Your issue is not in the code you've shown. It's at `MainNet.Global.Application_BeginRequest`. Always look in the stack trace for the highest line of your code, which is usually where the problem lies. Check your global.asax or global.asax.cs file

Comment: As it turned out, the issue was in an AppSettings.config file that has settings for the application. It was missing some values. But the tip to read the stack trace helped to start digging. 

There was nothing in the MainNet.Global.Application_BeginRequest that specifically loaded the AppSettings.Config file so I assume it is automatically read as a base part of the MainNet.Global.Application_BeginRequest event, as part of the application life cycle, yes?

Comment: Show the relevant code in your question.